# SQL - max of sum revenue by month by country

Tags: sql, max

I'm trying to find the record revenue months by for each country. Below query provides me revenue by month for each country.

```
select d.calendar_year_month as 'Record_month',
c.country_name as 'country'
,sum(Net_qty*(unit_charge+unit_shipping_charge)) as 'Revenue'

from sensu_reporting.commercial_analysts.customer_science_transactions CST (nolock)
join Sensu.dbo.Country_D C (nolock) on cst.country_code = c.Country_Code
join sensu.dbo.Date_D d (nolock) on cst.Order_Date_Key = d.Date_Key


where cst.site_key in ('95')
and cst.order_date_key >= 20180101

group by d.calendar_year_month, c.country_name
```

I tried using:

```
select a.country,
a.record_month,
max(a.revenue) as 'Record_Revenue'

from(
select d.calendar_year_month as 'Record_month',
c.country_name as 'country'
,sum(Net_qty*(unit_charge+unit_shipping_charge)) as 'Revenue'

from sensu_reporting.commercial_analysts.customer_science_transactions CST (nolock)
join Sensu.dbo.Country_D C (nolock) on cst.country_code = c.Country_Code
join sensu.dbo.Date_D d (nolock) on cst.Order_Date_Key = d.Date_Key


where cst.site_key in ('95')
and cst.order_date_key >= 20180101

group by d.calendar_year_month, c.country_name)
a 
group by country, record_month
```

However, this provides me the same data as the initial query. What am I doing wrong, and how do I amend my query such that it gives me only the month with the highest revenue per country?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't know your table structure this is an simplified example with only one table (id, calendar_year_month, countrycode, revenue). I used a subquery to identify the max revenue.

```
select calendar_year_month, country, revenue
from reporting r
where revenue = (select max(revenue) from reporting r2 where r.country = r2.country )
group by calendar_year_month, country
```

And the result I got was like this

> 201802 NO  1500
>   201802  SE  3000
>   201803  DE  7000
>   201803  NO  1500

Notice there are two rows for NO.
I hope this is translatable to your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
with r as (
      select d.calendar_year_month as Record_month,
             c.country_name as country,
             sum(Net_qty*(unit_charge+unit_shipping_charge)) as Revenue
      from sensu_reporting.commercial_analysts.customer_science_transactions CST join
           Sensu.dbo.Country_D C
           on cst.country_code = c.Country_Code join
           sensu.dbo.Date_D d
           on cst.Order_Date_Key = d.Date_Key
       where cst.site_key in ('95') and cst.order_date_key >= 20180101
       group by d.calendar_year_month, c.country_name
      )
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by record_month order by revenue desc) as seqnum
      from r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```